# Replace params in javascript

Tags: javascript

I tried a lot to replace the query parammeter using Javascript. But its not working. Can you please share any solutions to replace the parameter

Below is the example

```
console.log("www.test.com?x=a".replace(new RegExp(`${"x=a"}&?`),''));
```

the output i am getting is [www.test.com](http://www.test.com)? . Is there any way to replace ? and to get only [www.test.com](http://www.test.com).

Comment: why are you using a template parameter that's just a hardcoded string?

Comment: You want to remove whaever comes from the question mark including it?

Comment: Why do you need a regex for "?x=a". You could just split. Or just hard code in replace

Comment: Use the [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) constructor. `new URL(url).hostname`  should work

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove whatever comes from the question mark including it, try this instead:

```
console.log("www.test.com?x=a".split("?")[0]);
```

That way you get only what's before the question mark.

I hope that helps you out.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove all query strings using the following regex:

```
\?(.*)
```

```js
const url = "www.test.com?x=1&b=2"
console.log(url.replace(/\?(.*)/, ''));
```

Comment: Sorry I new to JS, I want to remove only first parameter and not all.  i dont want to remove all query strings. I want to remove only "x=1" and the output should be like www.test.com?b=2

Comment: @Ramya this is why you need to create a [mcve] with inputs that cover all scenarios, the expected behavior and a clear problem statement. From the question, it isn't clear whether you want to get the hostname, remove the query string or only a part of the query string.

Answer (score 0):

You could brutally replace the '?x=a' string with the JavaScript [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function or, even better, you could split the string in two (based on the index of `?`) with the JavaScript [`split`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) function and take the first part, e.g.:

```js
let str = 'www.test.com?x=a';
console.log(str.replace('?x=a', ''));
console.log(str.split('?')[0]);
```